# toDataURL crashing Chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas, hyperlink, three.js, todataurl

So I am working on a Tile Renderer for three.js, and everything seems to be working.

The way that it functions is as follows:

a) Creates a bunch of cameras,
b) Renderers the scene in each camera
c) creates a 'toDataURL', and downloads it.

Some Code:

```
  this.renderer.render( this.scene , this.camera );

  var imgData = this.renderer.domElement.toDataURL();      

  //this.imageData.push( imgData );

  var a = document.createElement('a');

  a.href = imgData;

  a.download = this.title + "_"+this.x+"_"+this.y+".png";
  a.click();
```

Now because I am doing this multiple times, ( Ideally a arbitrarily large amount of times ). It can end up producing hundreds of images.

Doing so crashes my chrome tab. Literally every time. I was wondering if there was anyway to stop this from happening? Either by setting a flag when I run chrome, or doing something with the code. I've tried doing things like setting timeouts for each render call ( AKA pause the renderer, than render 1 image and save it out every 10 seconds ), but even this seems to not work.

You can check out the crash here: http://cabbi.bo/ENOUGH/ ( press 'p' to try and capture the images , and the page takes a moment to load ).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Isaac / Cabbibo

Comment: It's probably running out of memory **base64 data uri memory footprints are huge compared to the binary data**; slow the loop down a bit so that the `toDataURL` will have some time to process (i.e. use a _setTimeout_ loop) and make sure the node gets removed after the click

Comment: Yeah, thats the first step I tried. Do you think each image might require more than 10 seconds to process ?

Comment: After more investigation, it seems that it will break, even when I call it a single time, and has more to do with it trying to automatically download the image than the size of the toDataURL ...

Comment: This is still true in 2022 (Chrome "Aw, Snaps" with error code 4)-- are they planning to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

On my box, saving large images as PNGs crashes Chrome (OS X 10.10, Chrome 40). Saving the [image as a JPG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL) fixes the issue here. I'm guessing the PNG data string is too large.

```
var imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Comment: This will lead to an image with faulty colors

Comment: Definitely not an answer.
Question is how to fix this issue when creating PNG files.